# Object Composition - Should a Constituent Know the Composing Object?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, aggregation, composition

I'm building an application that has reports, and each report contains several results. This is definitely a HAS-A composition type relationship between report and result.

My question is this: should a result know to which report it belongs?

Method A (where a result doesn't know which report it belongs to):

```
Report:
    name
    id
    results[]


Result:
    value
    type
    id
```

Method B (where a result knows which report it belongs to, but the report doesn't contain the results):

```
Report:
    name
    id

Result:
    value
    type
    id
    report_id
```

Comment: This entirely depends on your domain and as such cannot be answered by the community.

Comment: I would add that it also depends on the type of object model we're talking about - business model ? Presentation model ? Persistence model ? Can the objects be modified ? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible to answer this question with the information given, so instead of a straight forward answer, lets look at the things that might influence the  decision:

**Do you need the back reference?** Obviously, if you don't need it, don't create it. If you do need it though you might still be able to replace it with some kind of Repository lookup like: `ReportRepository.findReport(Result)`

**What are the costs for the backreference vs. the cost of not having it?** If you include a backreference, if the ownership changes (probably won't happen in your case) two references need to be kept in sync. If you don't have the backreference but need to navigate in this direction you have to jump through extra hoops. When persisting bidirectional relations, things like JPA mappings become much more complex. Same thing might apply when you need to serialize Results in some way.

It might also be worth it to look in to the [Aggregate pattern from DDD](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) although it doesn't seem to apply in your case.

Comment: You're right about the need for sync between references when the association is bidirectional, but it doesn't seem to be the case in the OP's example.

Comment: @guillaume31 That's why I wrote "probably won't happen in your case"

Comment: Yet it seems you were talking about the low probabilty of the ownership changing, not the low probability of there being a bidirectional relationship...